# Combination spy novel and horror regarding "mind vampires"

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

I am trying to track down a novel I read in December 1990 on my way to Saudi Arabia. Lost the book. It melded some Navy "moles" in the Pentagon funneling secrets (about a new plane) to the Russians along with a young Israeli counterintelligence officer and his family being murdered by a strange organization that had ties to a society of "mind vampires" I believe.

With the assistance of the man's uncle, the FBI(?) finally tracks down the killer(s) at the same time exposing the mole who kills himself by running in front of a bus while jogging and the other becomes homeless and ends up freezing to death on the street.

Am I perhaps confusing two novels (*Minotaur*) and something else?

Comment: Could it be Brian Lumley's Necroscope?  That's the first thing I thought of.

Comment: I scanned the Wikipedia entry for the series. I do not believe so.  This takes place around Washington, DC for the most part. The characters seem to American except for the Israeli and his family.  I think the uncle was American(dual?) citizenship. Also these do not feed on flesh, the feeding was more psychic I think.

Comment: The book appears to have some elements of "Carrion Comfort" by Dan Simmons